# Apply specific class or default using ng-class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I would like to apply a certain class depending the value of a variable.
I know how to use ng-class usually, but my case is a bit special.

Here is my code :

```
<div ng-class="{'col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-ms-12 col-xs-12': field.LongQuestion, subCategory.DefaultSize: !field.LongQuestion}">
```

If "LongQuestion" is true, I want to set the class to '`col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-ms-12 col-xs-12`', otherwise, I want to use the value stored in 'DefaultSize' (which is, in this case, '`col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-ms-12 col-xs-12`').

I get this error :

> Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 76 of
>   the expression [{'col-lg-12] starting at [{4}].

Any idea how to use a class value store in a variable with ng-class ?

Comment: Please visit this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: I've already seen this one. But in his examples, he knows both class (if and else). Me, I only know the class if value is true, but the "else" class is stored in a variable, that can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-class="{'col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-ms-12 col-xs-12': field.LongQuestion, subCategory.DefaultSize: !field.LongQuestion}">
```

Instead of this, couldn't you just create a function for it?

I would do this:

```
<div ng-class="getCSSClass(field.LongQuestion, field.TrueClass, field.DefaultClass)"></div>
```

Then in the function you do the check:

```
  $scope.getCSSClass = function(class, trueClass, defaultClass) {
     if(class)
         return trueClass;
     else
         return defaultClass;
  }
```

Comment: I did this one, but I just wanted to prevent doing hard-coded CSS in my controller :/ If I haven't an other solution today, I will mark your answer as accepted

Comment: You could pass along more variables from the view and return that variable if true or false, then you don't need to hardcode any css classes. I've updated my answer.