# multiple conditions in ng-class along with default function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to give multiple conditions like this. It works but how should i define a default value ?

```
ng-class=" {className: valueToCheckForTruthiness, otherClassName: otherValue , 
getDefaultClass(service.type) } "
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply specific class or default using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415872/apply-specific-class-or-default-using-ng-class)

Comment: Sure... but it doesnt fit in my usecase. Answer given below is simple and works for my need. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use both Array syntax and evaluated expression at the same time. In your case it should be something like this:

```
[{'className': valueToCheckForTruthiness, 'otherClassName': otherValue} , 
getDefaultClass(service.type)]
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
 ng-class="{'className': valueToCheckForTruthiness, 'otherClassName': otherValue, getDefaultClass(service.type) }"
```